# Daily Notification

Tags: ios, ios7, xamarin

I am looking on some way to notify users with a custom message every 8 AM every day.
I need to do some data processing before I display the notification(Get the number of patients for the past 24 hours) and notify the user about the data I got using some sort of notification.

I tried to create a local notification that fires every 8 am in the morning and that is working except It is requiring me to specify it's alert message and alert body at the time of it's creation instead of on before alert show.

I am considering push notifications but I am not sure how complex this may be.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how can I process data and notify the user with the results every day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking with local notifications. They 100% require static content up front. You'll need to use push notifications to do this dynamically.

Comment: How can I set up fire date for remote notification ? Or Do I have to use push notifications and local notification together?

Answer (score 1):

A hack around can be to request background fetch time from the OS.  You can reschedule the notification every time the background time is allotted to you with the current number of patients in the last 24 hrs.  Just compute it every time the system gives you background time.

See [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) for scheduling background fetch time

Comment: That's something I actually tried. But the problem is I can't set up the background fetch time to what I want let's say 7:50 AM every morning. From the definition of The property minimumBackgroundFetchInterval is defined as
The minimum number of seconds that must elapse before another background fetch can be initiated. This value is advisory only and does not indicate the exact amount of time expected between fetch operations.

Comment: Correct but if you reschedule the notification every time it runs chances are it will have the most up to date notification probably within half an hour, when the user actually sees it.  Try it out and see what happens during normal use.

Comment: Can I run the background fetch say at 7:50 AM every morning? Or can I guarantee it was run around that time before I reschedule the notification?